# Javascript // printing string from 2 textboxes after click event

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, dom-events

I have an HTML file that has 2 textboxes and 1 click. The click button will print out the text input in the textbox. HTML FILE BELOW:

```
<main>
  <!--Input-->
  <section class="StudentAndCourseInfo">
    <!--Student Info-->
    <p>First Name</p>
    <input type="text" name="firstName">

    <p>Last Name</p>
    <input type="text" name=lastName>

    <button> Capture Name </button>
  </section>

  <!--Output-->
  <section class=registeredCourses ">
                <h2><i><u>Registered Courses</u></i></h2>
</main>
```

JavaScript

```
var main = function() {
  "use strict";

  var addCommentForCaptureName = function() {
    var $newComment = $("<p>");
    var commentText1 = $(".StudentAndCourseInfo input").val();
    var commentText2 = $(".StudentAndCourseInfo input").val();

    if (commentText1 !== "" && commentText2 !== "") {
      $newComment.text(commentText1 + commentText2 + " is registered for the following courses:");
      $(".registeredCourses").append($newComment);
    }
  }

  $(".StudentAndCourseInfo button").on("click", function(event) {
    addCommentForCaptureName();
  });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: what is the question? Also please let us know what is your problem here in code

Comment: Sorry about that. When I input text in the 2 textboxes, and click the button, the text does not appear in the registeredCourses section.

Comment: Hmm i changed all of them but I still get incorrect results. my full HTML code is

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please specify your question properly. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

When you use `".StudentAndCourseInfo input"` you always select the same (first) input.

Use the [attribute equals selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to select the element you want.

Also your final `<section>` element is missing its close tag.

e.g.

```js
var addCommentForCaptureName = function() {
  var $newComment = $("<p>");
  var commentText1 = $(".StudentAndCourseInfo input[name='firstName']").val();
  var commentText2 = $(".StudentAndCourseInfo input[name='lastName']").val();

  if (commentText1 !== "" && commentText2 !== "") {
    $newComment.text(commentText1 + " " + commentText2 + " is registered for the following courses:");
    $(".registeredCourses").append($newComment);
  }
};

$(".StudentAndCourseInfo button").on("click", function(event) {
  addCommentForCaptureName();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <!--Input-->
  <section class="StudentAndCourseInfo">
    <!--Student Info-->
    <p>First Name</p>
    <input type="text" name="firstName">

    <p>Last Name</p>
    <input type="text" name=lastName>

    <button> Capture Name </button>
  </section>

  <!--Output-->
  <section class="registeredCourses">
    <h2><i><u>Registered Courses</u></i></h2>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're fetching value from the first text box in both the statements. Thus, value of the first text box repeats. Since both of the textboxes have different names, you need to target those by the attribute selector before fetching the values.

Following is a working demo:

```js
var main = function() {
  "use strict";

  var addCommentForCaptureName = function() {
    var $newComment = $("<p>");
    var commentText1 = $(".StudentAndCourseInfo input[name=firstName]").val();
    var commentText2 = $(".StudentAndCourseInfo input[name=lastName]").val();

    if (commentText1 !== "" && commentText2 !== "") {
      $newComment.text(commentText1 + commentText2 + " is registered for the following courses:");
      $(".registeredCourses").append($newComment);
    }
  }

  $(".StudentAndCourseInfo button").on("click", function(event) {
    addCommentForCaptureName();
  });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <!--Input-->
  <section class="StudentAndCourseInfo">
    <!--Student Info-->
    <p>First Name</p>
    <input type="text" name="firstName">

    <p>Last Name</p>
    <input type="text" name=lastName>

    <button> Capture Name </button>
  </section>

  <!--Output-->
  <section class="registeredCourses">
    <h2><i><u>Registered Courses</u></i></h2>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the event handlers methods `on('click';,function...` is inside another `main` function & is private to `main` function.So no way the event will be attached to the element unless `main` is called.Trigger that method first by calling `main()`

Also it seems there is not need to put those two function inside the main method

```js
var main = function() {
  "use strict";

  var addCommentForCaptureName = function() {
    var $newComment = $("<p>");
    var commentText1 = $(".StudentAndCourseInfo input").val();
    var commentText2 = $(".StudentAndCourseInfo input").val();

    if (commentText1 !== "" && commentText2 !== "") {
      $newComment.text(commentText1 + ' ' + commentText2 + " is registered for the following courses:");
      $(".registeredCourses").append($newComment);
    }
  }

  $(".StudentAndCourseInfo button").on("click", function(event) {
    addCommentForCaptureName();
  })
}

main()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <!--Input-->
  <section class="StudentAndCourseInfo">
    <!--Student Info-->
    <p>First Name</p>
    <input type="text" name="firstName">

    <p>Last Name</p>
    <input type="text" name="lastName">

    <button> Capture Name </button>
  </section>

  <!--Output-->
  <section class="registeredCourses">
    <h2><i><u>Registered Courses</u></i></h2>
  </section>
</main>
```